# Import two exported classes with the same name

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

In typescript, using Angular 2, I need to import two classes with the same name, but lying in different paths.

The project is quite too big that I find it hard to change the exported class names.

Is there any way to alias the imported classes,

```
import {Class1} from '../location1/class1'
import {Class1} from '../location2/class1'
```

Answer (score 436, accepted):

You can use `as` like this:

```js
import {Class1} from '../location1/class1'
import {Class1 as Alias} from '../location2/class1'
```

You can find more about the ES6 import statement [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: In code then use 
Class1.anyMethod().  
and 
Alias.anyMethodLocation2()

Comment: @toskv Not working for default classes (import without curly braces).

Comment: Answer: default class is already an alias, so just name it any way you want without the ` as something`.