# How to import an interface from lib.dom.d.ts?

Tags: typescript

I need to define a `Element` interface in my code:

```
interface Element {
    // my declaration
}
```

But, I also need to access the `Element` type of `lib.dom.d.ts`.

How could I do?

Comment: can't you use as ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610294/import-two-exported-classes-with-the-same-name

Comment: To use `as`, I need to be able to import. But I don't even know how to import `Element` from `lib.dom.d.ts`

Comment: I think it's a global .did you check without any import.use import as for your interface use element for Dom default

Comment: You don't need to import it, it's already imported for you.

Comment: Yes, but the whole point is that if I define a `Element` interface, I lose the access to the default `Element` interface

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import two exported classes with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610294/import-two-exported-classes-with-the-same-name)

Comment: No. The question is already answered now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use this

```
export type DOMElement = globalThis.Element
```

`lib.dom` has already imported `Element` type for you, you can explicitly access that from globalThis

Answer (score 1):

From the global.d.ts:

```
/*
React projects that don't include the DOM library need these interfaces to compile.
React Native applications use React, but there is no DOM available. The JavaScript runtime
is ES6/ES2015 only. These definitions allow such projects to compile with only `--lib ES6`.

Warning: all of these interfaces are empty. If you want type definitions for various properties
(such as HTMLInputElement.prototype.value), you need to add `--lib DOM` (via command line or tsconfig.json).
*/
```

Just follow it, add 'compilerOptions/lib/dom' to the tsconfig.json.

Comment: How?? I already have "lib":["dom"] in my tsconfig

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Zunaib, I found the correct solution to my problem.

In a file, define:

```
export interface Element2 extends Element {}
```

then:

```
import { Element2 } from 'path1';
import { Element } from 'path2';
```

Comment: I won't upvote your solution because it doesn't solve my issue. I don't want to put on the top a non-working solution. But thank you for your help!

Comment: Well i'm glad my answer clicked for you with some modification.